# Uber OAuth authorization Error: error.invalid_request by using R's "ubeR" package

Tags: r, uber-api

I tried to simply use R to estimate the trip cost between 2 places using Uber. I carefully followed each step on https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ubeR/versions/0.1.4.

After I created a new app in Uber Developer, I copied the client ID and client secret to R using `uber_oauth(UBER_CLIENTID, UBER_CLIENTSECRET)`, then an authentication page in browser popped up. I entered my account information and I am 100% sure they were correct, but then the Uber webpage showed

> "Authorization Error: error.invalid_request".

I am not a computer engineer so I don't know much about app development. Does anyone who used `ubeR` package in R before know how to solve this problem?

I tried created 3 different apps and tried 2 browsers, but neither helped.